# How to limit my CPU power programmatically on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, power-management, overclocking

Whenever I run a CPU-heavy activity (like compressing a big set of files into an archive for example) my CPU switches to its full throttle (maximum frequency) and shuts down of overheat in less than a minute.

Instead, I would like it to keep slowed-down slightly to do the task a bit slower but be able to reach the finish.

At the same time I don't want to dim my screen brightness or adjust anything else what standard Windows power-saving system does.

So how do I actually set a cap to limit my CPU power?

The CPU is Core 2 Duo T7250, the OS is Windows 7 32-bit, there seem to be no BIOS settings or jumpers available to configure the frequencies.

Comment: If your CPU is overheating and shutting down, something is *wrong* and you should fix it. Does the fan work? Is the heat sink free of dust?

Comment: There might be a utility for manipulating the frequencies etc available for you motherboard, but definitely agree with David above. Given you ask this, you haven't done any overclocking (despite of the tag you included), right?

Comment: Well, the laptop is quite old already and was always too powerful for its design. I'd prefer to limit the performance (which is more than enough for me) slightly rather than to disassemble it - disassembling and reassembling a laptop is always a huge headache.

Comment: The fan works ok of course, it is easy to hear and feel the strong flow of hot air out of it, but it is not enough. Perhaps there is too many dust inside or something.

Comment: I have already tried Notebook Hardware Control and RightMark CPU clock utilities but they are too complicated (even for me, a PC tweaking veteran doing the things since the era of 286s) and somewhat nasty to use when all I need is to set the clock top limit.

Comment: The mission is very easy to accomplish in Linux by the way, but unfortunately I need Windows 7 for some practical reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:

*Control Panel* → *Power Options* → *Change plan settings* → *Change advanced power plan settings*.

Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable* and expand *Processor power management*.

Set *Maximum processor state* to something around 70%.

Comment: Why did you post two seperate answers which both are very low quality?

Comment: @Ramhound this post exactly answers OP's question: this method does limit CPU power programmatically on Windows and it doesn't require any additional software. I believe it's the question that isn't asked properly ([XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), this answer seems perfectly valid to me. Posting multiple answers on one question is allowed to avoid mixing two completely different solutions.

Comment: @gronostaj - The question I thought I voted on was the original revision. I personal feel the lack of details is lacking. For some odd reason I actually voted on your revision.  My comment is based on the loq quality of both answers.  I have my doubts that changing the affinity of a process will prevent overheating that is happening in less then 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. A perfect solution. A little offtopic but just out of curiosity, perhaps you may know: is there similar functionality available in XP?

Comment: use CPU rightmark if it is XP .... that doesn't work on Window 7 only because of control register write contention of OS. which is introduce in Vista.

Comment: By the way, beware that override power options may consider "warranty void" to certain computer manufacturer if you burn you chip, "it really can if you set certain values totally wrong". that' why i gave 2 answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem, so I reduced the power to the CPU and it worked (But it did not fix the Problem)...

It worked for a few months, then I was back at square one.
The reason that the computer would shutdown while playing games or using some software...

**This is how I fixed the problem:**
The Processor has a heat sink above it. In between the processor and the heat sink is a compound called *thermal paste*. Sometimes you have to replace the  thermal paste, but you have to clean the old  thermal paste off first. Then apply new thermal paste.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You can right-click on a process a choose **Set Priority** to something like 'Below Normal'.

[image: Set Priority]

For a description of different priority levels have a look at the API documentation for [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How do you think that will help him?

Comment: Priorities affect how OS balances CPU load between multiple processes, but won't decrease CPU usage. Moreover, changing priorities is built into Windows Task Manager and no additional software is needed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's something to try, that's all.

Comment: @gronostaj Testing this out with 7z and choosing 'Background' I was able to significantly reduce CPU usage.